# Save the Output of for loop of a DataFrame to a DataFrame that is declared outside

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Is there any way to save the output of a dataframe that is evaluated inside a for loop to a data frame that is empty and is declared outside the for loop?
Can we save the output of for loop separately for every iteration?

```
new_dict1 = {'ABW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},'BCW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},
        'CBW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':0,'DBR':0},'MCW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':0,'DBR':1}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict1,orient="index")
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(2):
 df3 = df.iloc[0:3, 1:4]
 print(df3)
 #df4.append(df3)
```

Output Which I have got

```
         BPR  CBR  DBR
  ABW    1    1    0
  BCW    0    1    0
  CBW    1    0    0
         BPR  CBR  DBR
  ABW    1    1    0
  BCW    0    1    0
  CBW    1    0    0
```

The output which I have got is the output of two iterations of for loop when it is operated.
I want to save the output of every iteration of for loop outside the for loop within another dataframe.

Comment: you can build a dictionary in a loop

Comment: it simpler to remeber: append to list and after loop create your DataFrame `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `concat` the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
new_dict1 = {'ABW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},'BCW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},
    'CBW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':0,'DBR':0},'MCW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':0,'DBR':1}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict1,orient="index")
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(2):
    df3 = df.iloc[0:3, 1:4]
    df4 = pd.concat([df4, df3])
print(df4)
```